# Prove a subset is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{E}^{n}$ be the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let S be a subset of $\mathbb{E}^{n}$, and let V denote the set $S^{\prime}$, where $S^{\prime}$is the subset of $\mathbb{E}^{n}$ defined by the condition $$x \in S^{\prime} \iff  x*s= 0$$ for all $s \in S$ and where $*$ is the standard dot product in $$\mathbb{R}^{n}.$$ Prove that V is a subspace of $\mathbb{E}^{n}$.

Solution Attempt:

1. First I consider the case where $S$ is empty, which makes $S^{\prime}$ empty as well. If $S$ is empty, then $S^{\prime}$ is NOT a subspace.
2. Take $0 \in \mathbb{R}$. $(0)(x*s)=(0)(x)*s=(0)*s= 0 \implies 0 \in S^{\prime}$
3. From (2) we see also that if $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in V \implies cx \in V$ that is $$(cx*s) = c(x*s) = 0 \implies c(0) = 0$$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$and $x \in V.$
4. Since $\mathbb{E}^{n}$ is a vector space, let $x \in V$ and $-x=y$ with $-x \in V.$ Then we have $x+y \in V$ since $0*s=0$.

Therefore V is a subspace of $\mathbb{E}^{n}$

Comment: @Ian I think you mixed $S$ and $S'$ somewhere

Answer (score 1):

> 1. First I consider the case where $S$ is empty, which makes $S^{\prime}$ empty as well.

Be careful here.  If $S$ is empty, then for **any** $x \in \Bbb E^n$, we have $x \cdot s = 0$ **if** $s \in S$ (by vacuous implication).  So, $S' = \Bbb E^n$

> 2. Take $0 \in \mathbb{R}$. $(0)(x*s)=(0)(x)*s=(0)*s= 0 \implies 0 \in S^{\prime}$

Yes.  So, $0 \in S'$ regardless of how $S$ is chosen.

> 3. From (2) we see also that if $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in V \implies cx \in V$ that is $$(cx*s) = c(x*s) = 0 \implies c(0) = 0$$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$and $x \in V.$

Not sure what you mean by "from (2)", but otherwise this is fine

> 4. Since $\mathbb{E}^{n}$ is a vector space, let $x \in V$ and $-x=y$ with $-x \in V.$ Then we have $x+y \in V$ since $0*s=0$.

I haven't the foggiest notion of what you were trying to accomplish here.  Here's the step you're missing though: you need to show that if $x,y \in S'$, that is, if $x \cdot s = 0$ and $y \cdot s = 0$ for every choice of $s \in S$, then it is also true that $(x+y) \cdot s = 0$ for every choice of $s \in S$.

Comment: Thank you. I going to think about the first case. If I am understanding you correctly, then we have a conditional statement $p \implies q$, where $p$, i.e., $x \cdot s$ is always false, making the the implication necessarily true for any value of q.

Comment: Well, $p$ here would be $s \in S$.  But otherwise, yes.  It might not be the case that $q$ is true (i.e. we might not have $x \cdot s = 0$), but $p$ is **never** true (i.e. $s \in S$ can never be true if $S = \emptyset$).  So, for any choice of $x$, $p \implies q$.

Comment: I think for 4. I can say, by abusing notation a bit, that if $x,y \in S^{\prime}$ with $x \cdot s = 0$ and $y \cdot s = 0$ then $x \cdot s +y \cdot s = (x+y) \cdot s = 0  \implies x+y \in S^{\prime}$

Comment: In what way is that an abuse of notation?  That does the job perfectly.

Comment: Well, just because $x$ and $y$ could mean some sort of tuplet. But, it would work just the same.

Comment: Oh, okay, sure.  Anyway, you seem to have it. I would clean up that answer to 3 a bit, though.